# Analysis on Manifolds - Differentiability

Tags: analysis

Let $B:\mathbb{R^{n} x R^{n}}$$\longrightarrow$ a bilineal function. That is,

$B(ax+by,z)=aB(x,z)+bB(y,z)$

$B(x,ay+bz)=aB(x,y)+bB(x,z)$ $\hspace{4mm}$    for all $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ and for all $x,y,z\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$.

1. Prove that exist $M>0$ such that $B(x,y)\leq M\left \| x \right \|\left \| y \right \|$ $\hspace{3mm}$  for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$
2. Using the previous item prove that $B$ is differentiable in all ${mathbb{R^{n}} x R^{n}}

Answer (score -1):

Let us write $$x = \sum_{j=1}^{n}\alpha_{j}e_{j} \quad \mbox{and} \quad y = \sum_{j=1}^{n}\beta_{j}e_{j}$$
where $e_{1},...,e_{n}$ is the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Then, the bilinearity of $B$ implies: $$B(x,y) = \sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\alpha_{j}\beta_{k}B(e_{j},e_{k})$$
So that $$|B(x,y)| \le \sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}|\alpha_{j}||\beta_{k}||B(e_{j},e_{k})|$$
Now, set $M := \sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}|B(e_{j},e_{k})|$. Besides, note that $$|\alpha_{j}| \le \max_{j\in\{1,...,n\}}|\alpha_{j}| := \bar{\alpha}$$ $$|\beta_{k}|\le \max_{k\in\{1,...,n\}}|\beta_{k}|:=\bar{\beta}$$
So, putting all together, we have $$|B(x,y)| \le \bar{\alpha}\bar{\beta}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}|B(e_{j},e_{k})| = M\bar{\alpha}\bar{\beta}$$
Finally, noting that $$|x| =\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^{n}\alpha_{j}^{2}} \ge \bar{\alpha}$$ $$|y|=\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{n}\beta_{k}^{2}} \ge \bar{\beta}$$
We conclude $$|B(x,y)|\le M|x||y|$$

Can you use this to prove your second question?